# Closed respect a norm $\|\cdot\|$

Tags: functional-analysis

What mean that expression "closed respect a norm". For example:

$$H^{m,p}(\Omega)= \overline{\left\{{u\in C^m(\Omega); \|u\|_{W^{m,p}}<\infty}\right\}}^{\|\cdot\|}$$

Comment: The grammatical version of "closed respect a norm $\|\cdot\|$" is *closed with respect to the norm* $\|\cdot\|$"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that in the topology generated by this norm, the set is closed. Since norms are metrics, this means that all the $\|\cdot\|$-convergent sequences from this set have limits inside this set as well.

Comment: I will be able to write 

$$H^{m,p}(\Omega)= \overline{\left\{{u\in C^m(\Omega); \|u\|_{NORM1}<\infty}\right\}}^{NORM2}$$
You saw that differents norms?

Comment: @user46060: I just saw now that those are different norms. That doesn't matter, though. This is just a definition of a particular set, and you claim that it is closed under $NORM_2$, meaning all $NORM_2$-convergent sequences find their limit within this set.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you take the closure of $\left\{{u\in C^m(\Omega); \|u\|_{W^{m,p}}<\infty}\right\}$ with respect to $\| \cdot \|$. The closure is the set itself together with all its limit points. And a limit point is a point such that every $\varepsilon$-ball around it has non-empty intersection with the set.